# While(matcher.find()) - Error - Doesn't Work

Tags: java, android, while-loop, pattern-matching, runtime-error

I need a sort help

I don't know why it's jump in the while by matcher.find() when i'm have the string "3*3"

code:

```
    public void delSin_Cos_Tan()
            {
                o = new ArrayList<>();
                String aDate = "3*3";
                Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("((sin|cos|tan|sinh|cosh|tanh|asin|acos|atan)\\((.+)\\))"); 
//Operat.Sin_Cos_Tan.Patter = ((sin|cos|tan|sinh|cosh|tanh|asin|acos|atan)\((.+)\))
                Matcher matcher = datePattern.matcher(aDate);
                Log.d(TAG,"Sin Startz");
                Log.d(TAG,"Sin " + Aufgabe);
                while (matcher.find());
                {
                    Log.e(TAG,matcher.group(1)); // there is the Error, but withe the String "3*3" an i don't konw why it is jump inside the while  
                    String Gesammt = matcher.group(1);
                    String TYP = matcher.group(2);
                    String Inklammer = matcher.group(3);

                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf("------------------------"));
                    Log.d(TAG, Gesammt);
                    Log.d(TAG, Inklammer);
                    Log.d(TAG, TYP);
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf("------------------------"));
               }
            }
```

My completely Code: http://pastebin.com/jWN1ghfz

Comment: Please clarify what is being asked. Also, the code uses 3 TIMES 3, while you have written 3 PLUS 3.

Comment: describe your problem please

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do please clarify it in your question?

Comment: My problem is, i use the patter "((sin|cos|tan|sinh|cosh|tanh|asin|acos|atan)\((.+)\))" and this can find only "sin(5) or sin(896)" but is find "3*3" with the patter, an then i'm get a error

Comment: My exactly Question is why it jump in the while with this patter ? when i'm have 3*3

Comment: below the code there is my completely code.

Comment: What is this ? `Operat.Sin_Cos_Tan.Patter` its a `static` variable or something else?

Comment: Subodh Joshi, i have chance it. :), and i have adding a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got a `;`after your while loop.
This is why your complete block will always get executed!

`while (matcher.find());` should be `while (matcher.find())` (whithout `;`)

It's because

```
while (matcher.find());
{
 //...
}
```

is the same as

```
while (matcher.find()){
;
}

{
 //...
}
```

Comment: on what Position  ? You mean "while(true) {...};" ??

Comment: I'm doesn't have see the character ";" xD fail

Comment: @Facebamm this happens ... ;)